# Mobx: Is there any possibilities to set hook on get property in observable object?

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I have an observable object. And use it in react observered component. Can I have some callback when mobx get any properties in this object?
Example:

```
@observable obj; // in some class that will be a store

@observer
class Test extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  render() {
    <div>{this.props.obj.user.name}</div>
  }
}
```

I want to add callback when mobx get any properties from obj, like:

```
obj.on('get', (target, value) => {
  console.log(target, value);
})
```

and in this case I should get it twice fired (for user and name)

Answer (score 0):

You can `intercept` and `observe` objects and properties that are managed by mobx.

Intercept is usually used for guarding against certain values.

Observe is used for observing what changed.

```js
const disposer = observe(obj,(change) => {
    console.log(change.type, change.name, "from", change.oldValue, "to", change.object[change.name]);
  if('get' === change.name){
    // obj.get value is changed
  }
});
```

More information in official documenation: [Intercept & Observe](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/observe.html)

Comment: Thank you but I know about this functions and that's not I'm looking for. Firstly I need intercept deep. Secondly I need to have ability to do smth when mobx add prop as observable. When it generate observable property configuration